# Can Doctrine2 load calculated values?

Tags: php, orm, datamapper, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to load calculated values into an entity using Doctrine2? For example, if a `question` has `votes` (the `votes` table having a foreign key from the `question` table), using SQL you could select the `question` and calculate a vote total.

Is something like that possible with Doctrine2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the following way:

```
SELECT q, count(v.id) FROM Question q JOIN q.votes WHERE <condition> GROUP BY q.id
```

Another approach would be using an aggregate column like described here:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/cookbook/aggregate-fields/en#aggregate-fields

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link - I was looking though the reference, not the cookbook.

Comment: Seems like the aggregate column adds a bit of complexity with consistency checking; however that may be worth the gain from not having the database calculate the values each time (certainly worth not loading the collection).

Comment: The link is broken, here it is : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html#aggregate-fields